# SQL Server permissions per column invisible to users

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

Can I set up permission on certain columns in db and grant to another in a way that's transparent to the users, let say I have a following grant:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[DIM_Table1](Field1 , Field2 , Field4 ) TO [NDMRole] ; 
-- column Field3 is missing, it's prohibited to select for this user.
```

if the user tries to do:

```
SELECT * from Dim_Table1
```

she will get an error saying that `Field3` is not allowed to be selected. Is there a way to make this field invisible to user or somehow make it so the user doesn't get an error.

I don't want to create additional views for this. The reason I don't want to create views is there are a lot of users of the systems with different permissions and it will be too much effort to maintain this complex mechanism, a solution with permissions will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Check out the [sp_column_privileges](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187765.aspx) and [Column Permission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180341%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> ```
>  sp_column_privileges [ @table_name = ] 'table_name' 
>  [ , [ @table_owner = ] 'table_owner' ] 
>  [ , [ @table_qualifier = ] 'table_qualifier' ] 
>  [ , [ @column_name = ] 'column' ]
> ```

Comment: I understand I can set permissions on a column as per example in the question, but how do I make sure select * from table works if some of the columns are not granted select permission?